# Is there a way to get the traceback stack from Dagster failure_hook and success_hook?

Tags: python-3.x, dagster

```
from dagster import HookContext, failure_hook, success_hook


@success_hook(required_resource_keys={"slack"})  
def slack_message_on_success(context: HookContext):  
    message = f"Solid {context.solid.name} finished successfully"
    context.resources.slack.chat.post_message(channel="#foo", text=message)


@failure_hook(required_resource_keys={"slack"})
def slack_message_on_failure(context: HookContext):
    message = f"Solid {context.solid.name} failed"
    context.resources.slack.chat.post_message(channel="#foo", text=message)
```

Is there a field to pull traceback stacks from 'context' to locate the exception triggered and send out an email or slack message?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not currently supported in Dagster and here is the [GH issue](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/issues/3631) to track this request.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating you that this is now supported.

```
context.op_exception.with_traceback(context.op_exception.__traceback__)
```

So something like:

```
slack.chat_postMessage(channel=dagster_flow, context.op_exception.with_traceback(context.op_exception.__traceback__))
```